# MySQL: Is it possible to compute MAX( AVG (field) )?

Tags: mysql, average

My current query reads:

```
SELECT entry_id, user_id, cat_id, AVG( rating ) as avg_rate
FROM `entry_rate`
WHERE 1
GROUP BY entry_id
```

`cat_id` relates to different categories: 1, 2, 3 or 4

Is there a way I can find the maximum average for **each user** in **each category** without setting up an additional table? The return could potentially be 4 maximum avg_rate for each user_id

Visit the link below for example:

http://lh5.ggpht.com/_rvDQuhTddnc/S8Os_77qR9I/AAAAAAAAA2M/IPmzNeYjfCA/s800/table1.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May not be the most efficient way:

```
select user_id, cat_id, MAX(avg_rate)
FROM (
    SELECT entry_id, user_id, cat_id, AVG( rating ) as avg_rate
    FROM entry_rate
    GROUP BY entry_id, user_id, cat_id) t
GROUP BY user_id, cat_id
```

Comment: You need to group by entry_id and user_id in the inner query as well.. Also, `WHERE 1` is not needed.

Comment: @BlueRaja, you're right, I just copied his query which also has those problems. Fixed.

Comment: @tloflin and @BlueRaja- oh my God! you guys are wizards! I've been going over that for a while with no luck (granted I'm a newb...). THANK YOU!

BTW, what is the 't' for on the end of the 5th line? That's the one element I don't understand.

Comment: That "t" is the name of the entity that you're selecting from. See how you've got that "from" keyword, and then the sub-query in parentheses? Well, it's treating the sub-query as a table, so it needs a name for the table (for instance, if you were to join it with another table, or if another table had a "user_id" field and you needed to distinguish them).

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, you named the sub-query "t" even though you weren't referencing it later in the query.

(and I see that you can omit the label as...)

Comment: @Brad, right. It has to be named no matter what, but you don't have to reference it, just like you have to give a table name in a FROM clause but you don't have to use it anywhere else (unless there are conflicts).

Answer (score 4):

You can make this statement.

```
SELECT entry_id, user_id, cat_id, AVG( rating ) as avg_rate

FROM 'entry_rate'

GROUP BY entry_id

order by AVG( rating ) DESC

limit 1
```

this make the result order by `avg(rating)` and select the first row. and can make the `limit 1`,`1` to select the second max element

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT s.user_id,s.cat_id,max(s.avg_rate) FROM (
  SELECT entry_id, user_id, cat_id, AVG( rating ) as avg_rate
  FROM entry_rate
  GROUP BY entry_id,user_id,cat_id) as s 
GROUP BY  s.user_id,s.cat_id
```

Comment: This is also a great answer! Thanks (but a little too slow for the green check mark!)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT entry_id, user_id, cat_id, AVG( rating ) as avg_rate
FROM `entry_rate`
GROUP BY entry_id
order by avg_rate desc limit 1;

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please use formatting to make your answer more readable using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). Also, adding a context to your answer would make future readers understand it a bit more.